# Silent Install Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8

Tags: windows, automation, windows-server-2012, sdk, silent-install

I am writing my first Powershell script to automate the installation of Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8. I plan to install it on a Hyper-V VM running on Windows Server 2012. I have the .exe file (sdksetup.exe) necessary for the install. I've looked into answer files, but it seems they require a disc. I need to be able to press "Next" a few times, uncheck some preset boxes, and agree to a EULA, all automatically. I am fine with the default location of installation as well. It seems so simple, yet I haven't found any really good resources on the web yet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you'll consider an alternative, I'd suggest using [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) or [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to write a [simple](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/scite/docs/SciTE4AutoIt3/SciTE4AutoIt3-getting-started.html) [automation script](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/tutorials/winzip/winzip.htm). You can compile them to EXE as well so they will run on any Windows machine.

Comment: Alternatively, try `setup.exe /q` however, [you're required to accept the EULA](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2007/08/03/can-i-install-the-windows-sdk-in-quiet-mode.aspx) so maybe automate that using AutoIT or AutoHotkey. If you want to use PowerShell, installing the [WASP snap-in](https://wasp.codeplex.com/) or the [UI Automation extention](https://uiautomation.codeplex.com/) might help.

Answer (score 4):

You can silent install the Windows 8.1 SDK with `sdksetup.exe /quiet`
No need to accept EULA